# Upgraded to Pydev 3 not working with eclipse 4.3 Kepler on Mac 64 bit cocoa

Tags: eclipse, pydev

I have tried using a clean workspace and a fresh installation of eclipse with nothing but pydev. In all cases, I don't get the pydev configuration options or preferences or views. The plugin install goes through without a hitch and I can see pydev in the installed software also. Anybody else face the same?

Comment: I get this too, works fine with 2.8.2.

Comment: I had a similar problem when I updated to PyDev 3. You should ensure you have an updated version of Java 7, and you can't just install the JRE, because that will not replace the Mac OS X version of Java, you will need to install the JDK: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html

Answer (score 0):

PyDev 3 requires Java 7 to function. Unfortunately, the version of Java that is installed on Mac OS X is not a compatible or recent version.

You can check the current version of java on your system by typing `java -version` in the terminal. In order to run PyDev 3 you should have version 1.7.xxx.

To update Java you will need to install a [Java Development Kit (JDK)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html), since just installing the Java Runtime Environment (JRE) will not update the symlink at /usr/bin/java on OS X. If you think that you have installed Java 7, but `java -version` still gives you a version of 1.6.xxx then you probably installed the JRE instead of the JDK.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with pseudocubic, In my case I just downloaded [JDK8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) : which by the way includes the JRE8 so pydev worked without trouble in my mac . I had to do this after installing JRE7 but when checking in console `java -version` it was returning 1.6 version (despite the fact that checking at java icon in system preferences says 1.7 was installed)

Install [JDK8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) and it's done